# MoveIt2 compatibility with ROS2 Humble on Windows

Tags: windows, ros2, moveit

I see now the required dependencies to build moveit2 are included in ros-foxy-desktop for installation on Windows. According to: https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/binary-windows/. Is MoveIt2 compatible with ROS2 Humble on Windows as well? Would there be differences if I clone the MoveIt2 Humble branch with installation of ROS2 Humble on Windows instead?

If there is anyone has tried installing MoveIt2 with ROS2 Humble on Windows, please let me know if it works or not. I need to use some features in MoveIt2 Humble version. Any help would be greatly appreciated!